# The error says "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" in c#

Tags: c#, .net

this code is for the combo box where i want to select some index to show it to my textboxes.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM GuestInfo WHERE Groomno= '" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
        db.connectDB();
        db.da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, db.conn);
        db.executeQryCommand(query, false);
        maxRecord = db.ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        loadRecords(recordCounter);
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr["Gname"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dr["Gcontactno"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! " + er.Message);
    }
}
```

//My program is completely running but not in this section. :(

Comment: What is in the variable `conn`?  How was it initialized?  By the way, you either need to use a `using` block for the IDisposable objects (e.g. conn, cmd) or clean them up in a finally block.

Comment: Update your code with `conn` details.

Comment: [**SQL Injection alert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the connection string for the connection, here i suggest you one best method for executing command.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("yourconnectionString"))
  {
     conn.Open();
     using (OleDbCommand  cmd =new OleDbCommand("your query text",  conn))
       {
         // execute your command
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you made an connection between your application and database source using conn object ? You might be used conn object as a connection object but before this was you initialized you Connection ?
Simpy use like

"SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection("Connection_Source");"

here is your error.

Answer (score 0):

If its just to select value from comboBox and display in textBox , then below code will help you...

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Gname,Gcontactno FROM GuestInfo WHERE Groomno= '" + comboBox2.Text + "'", conn);
        OleDbDataReader  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! " + er.Message);
    }
}
```